# Fetching list of tags of an EMR Cluster using AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

Is there any function to get list of tags of an emr cluster like S3 bucket? Like in a S3 bucket, we have get_bucket_tagging

I tried using get_list but it does not work. Let me know if there is any other way to fetch the tag details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tags by using [describe_cluster](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr/client/describe_cluster.html#EMR.Client.describe_cluster) method. For example, using boto3:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('emr')
response = client.describe_cluster(
    ClusterId='string'
)
tags = response['Cluster']['Tags']
```